# Handler Image Display on Null Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, httphandler

I am trying to create Handler, and I am trying to have it return a default picture when it returns a null value. But when I access this via a page using the second code bit below, I get an error image. But If I go directly to the page Image.ashx?id=28 and no images exist I get my default image, why isnt it showing up on my page? And If an image does exist it displays that image on the page and if directly called.

Thanks

My Image.ashx File:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        string id = ctx.Request.QueryString["id"];

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONN INFO);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EventInviteImage FROM Events WHERE EventID = @EventID", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", id);

        byte[] pict = null; 

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            pict = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();            

            ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/pjpeg";
            ctx.Response.BinaryWrite(pict);
        }
        catch
        {
            ctx.Response.Write("<img src='/images/defaultevent.jpg'>");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }



    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Calling Image:

```
<img src="Image.ashx?id=28" />
```

Comment: Your handler needs to stream the binary data for the default image itself. Not the HTML image tag.

Comment: @Martin When you refer to binary data, you are not referring to the path I take it. What are you referring to, could you give me an example?

Comment: @Martin If I use `ctx.Response.BinaryWrite("path to defaultevent.jpg");` or `ctx.Response.BinaryWrite(Server.MapPath("~/images/defaultevent.jpg"));` it says that it has invalid arguments.

Comment: Yes. I think you may well need `Response.WriteFile` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
   ...
   ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/pjpeg";
   ctx.Response.BinaryWrite(pict);
}
catch
{
   ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/pjpeg";
   ctx.Response.Write("<img src='/images/defaultevent.jpg'>");
}
```

You are doing very different things in the `try` and the `catch` - instead of writing a `string` in your catch, you should be returning the file:

```
catch
{
  ctx.Response.WriteFile("path to defaultevent.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Do you need `WriteFile` rather than `BinaryWrite`?